# Apache and Varnish http/https

Tags: linux, apache, debian, varnish

I use apache2 and varnish on a debian server, but i have 2 websites one use port 80 and other 443 but i dont have idea for use this with varnish

How i can use port 80 and 443 with varnish ?
Thanks you

/etc/default/varnish

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,256m"
```

/etc/varnish/default.vcl

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}
```

and apache2

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
```

Comment: Not really a programming problem; try http://serverfault.com/questions or http://superuser.com/questions ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "recommended" TLS termination companion to Varnish would be [Hitch](https://hitch-tls.org/), which is from the same developers. It runs as an independent process and uses the HAProxy PROXY protocol to communicate with Varnish. What this entails Varnish-wise is listening on another port for the PROXY protocol.

Per the [Varnish 4.1 documentation](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/whats-new/changes.html#proxy-protocol-support), you would listen on both the 6081 (or 80 as the case may be) as well as the internal port, such as 6086

```
varnishd -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -a :6081 -a 127.0.0.1:6086,PROXY
```

You can use the *std* module to detect whether the origin request came over SSL by doing something like:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (std.port(server.ip) == 443) {
        set req.http.X-Proto = "https";
    }
}
```